# Custom Category/Subcategory structure

Tags: categories, menus, url-rewriting, 404-error

I am building a site with several sections, and one of them is a special page to navigate through categories in a hierarchical style (you can navigate into categories/subcategories and see their children). So I have added a `Page` and I have assigned a custom template to it in the `Template` drop-down.

Maybe what I want to do is not possible, or it's too tricky: I'd like to have my page, which URL is `www.domain.com/tutorials` to display a top menu with the **main** categories. This menu is a WordPress menu registered with `register_nav_menus`, with links to categories.

I'd like the items on the menu to point to that same page, with the slug of the category: `www.domain.com/tutorials/my-category` (instead of `www.domain.com/category/my-category`).

Each "category page" will show links to sub-categories that should have the same URL structure (i.e.: `www.domain.com/tutorials/my-category/my-subcategory`)  I know how to query for sub-categories and get the current category with `get_query_var`, but again I have this problem producing the right URL for each one.

I've seen the pieces I need, like `add_rewrite_rule()`, `add_rewrite_tag()` or `parse_request()`. I can also have `wp_nav_menu_objects` and `Walker_Nav_Menu` but I can't put together a setup where my `Tutorials` page doesn't return a 404 if I add categories/subcategories to the URL (it only accepts going to `www.domain.com/category/my-category`).

I have been able to render a menu pointing to my page by getting each menu $item->url and replacing 'category' by my page's slug, so my only remaining issue is the 404 problem.

My WP settings are: `Category base` is empty, and my permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Set your category base to `tutorials` and that will set all the URLs the way you want them. It would also be easier to maintain, and better practice, to set up your theme templates to handle the lists of categories. Instead of using a `wp_nav_menu` which you have to manually maintain, use `wp_list_categories`. Once you have your permalinks set the way you want, be sure to clear your cache or use an incognito window to check whether the new URLs are working. Once they are there are plugins to check which template file each page is using, so you can tell what file to modify for `/tutorials/`.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds good, although I have a couple of limitations. If I set my base category to 'tutorials', that will apply to all post types, including content in the blog and other sections.

About wp_list_categories, it also sounds right, but my client wants their editors to decide which are the main categories to want on top of the Tutorials page. They will have different categories in the site, and only 4 or 5 of them will be in this specific page.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: The menu limitation makes sense, but setting your base category should not apply to all post types, just Posts. Pages and CPTs will be unaffected (and if for some odd reason CPTs are affected, either you're using built-in Categories for them and can use a custom taxonomy instead, or else you need to change the CPT registration to set the permalinks as you need them).

Comment: I think the answer might be CPT actually. I want posts to be different from tutorials, so I will add a Tutorial post type and a template to list them with the hierarchy I described. Thanks for the suggestions and your time.